# Authenication of keystone js using stormpath

Tags: express, keystonejs

I am very new to Express and Keystone. Generally I would like to understand how to use Express apps in Keystone, ie, how to break down an Express  app and import it into Keystone, or integrate Express modules with Keystone. More specifically, and as a start, I would like to simply use Stormpath to authenticate my users. Stormpath provides an Express example. I I consider this to be a typical simple Express app, how do I incorporate this, or similar similar Express app's like this into Keystone, ie how do i break this down into it's corresponding pieces and files in Keystone?

Thanks!

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

var routes = require('./lib/routes');

/**
* Create the Express application.
 */
var app = express();

/**
* Application settings.
 */
app.set('trust proxy',true);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', './lib/views');
app.locals.siteName = 'Express-Stormpath Example Project';

/**
 * Stormpath initialization.
 */

console.log('Initializing Stormpath');

app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
expand: {
customData: true
```

}
   }));

```
/**
 * Route initialization.
 */
app.use('/', routes);

app.on('stormpath.ready',function () {
console.log('Stormpath Ready');
});

/**
 * Start the web server.
*/
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:' + port);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Express-Stormpath does NOT work with Keystone.js due to the way their loading works =/

NOTE: I'm the original author of the express-stormpath library, which is why I'm very familiar with this.